# Is it possible to run qc test set from outside the qc app?

Tags: c#, jenkins, cmd, vbscript, hp-quality-center

Our organization tries to make thing more "automatics". 
One of things, we are trying is to run "Tests Set" each night automatically.
Is there a way, to run the "Test Set" by command prompt or to write a small c sharp app that will run the "Set"?
I read about OTA library (also, i didn't understand if the library is only for c# or also for visual basic script)? 
Unfortunately, i didn't find a way how to do it.
Each assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to automate tests from `Quality Center`, you should look into the use of `UFT` as it's the automated test tool designed to work with it, from the same software company.

Answer (score 0):

Yes
Its quite feasible, we have have done same thing for our automation. For automated tests you will require to allocate UFT/QTP host to the test case or test suite. And using c#/vb.net code referencing HPALM OTAClient.dll library you can write a script to trigger specific test case or set of test cases/suite based on your need. Publish your script as exe with configuration properties that defines what to trigger and setup task scheduler to trigger it every night. I would be happy to help you if you are still working on this project.